# Child Menu in a dropdown under the Parent?

Tags: php, pdo, html5-canvas, navbar

Hiya everyone hope everyone is doing good?

Well am kinda stuck in here on how I make the sub menu to display in a dropdown under the parent name.

So far my php mysql codes are doing what it should but i am stuck in the HTML Nav section :(

Could one of you lovely people help me out in here?

Here is my complete menu codes along with php ans mysql

```
    <div class="rd-navbar-top-panel-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rd-navbar-inner">
      <!-- RD Navbar Panel-->
      <div class="rd-navbar-panel">
        <!-- RD Navbar Toggle-->
        <button class="rd-navbar-toggle" data-rd-navbar-toggle=".rd-navbar-nav-wrap"><span></span></button>
        <!-- RD Navbar Brand-->
        <div class="rd-navbar-brand"><a class="brand-name" href="<?php echo DIR; ?>"><img class="logo-default" src="<?php echo DIR; ?>images/logo.png" alt="" width="208" height="46"/><img class="logo-inverse" src="<?php echo DIR; ?>images/logo.png" alt="" width="208" height="46"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rd-navbar-aside-center">
        <div class="rd-navbar-nav-wrap">
          <!-- RD Navbar Nav-->
          <ul class="rd-navbar-nav .margin-right">
           <?php if($page_name =='index'){?>
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>index">Home</a></li>
            <?php }else{ ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>index">Home</a></li>
             <?php } ?>                      
            <?php
            ////PARENT MENU
            $stmt = $db->prepare('select * from pages where parentid is null');
            $stmt->execute();
            ?>              
            <?php while($menu = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { ?>
            <li>
            <?php if($page_name ==''.$menu->slug.''){?>     
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo DIR; ?><?php echo $menu->slug; ?>"><?php echo $menu->page_name; ?></a></li>      
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo DIR; ?><?php echo $menu->slug; ?>"><?php echo $menu->page_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            //CHILD MENU
            $stmt1 = $db->prepare('select * from pages where parentid = :pageid');
            $stmt1->bindValue('pageid', $menu->pageid);
            $stmt1->execute();
            ?>
            <?php if($stmt1->rowCount() > 0) { ?>                           
                            <?php while($sub_menu = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { ?>
                            <?php if($page_name ==''.$menu->slug.''){?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo DIR; ?><?php echo $sub_menu->slug; ?>"><?php echo $sub_menu->page_name; ?></a></li>
                            <?php }else{ ?> 
                                    <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo DIR; ?><?php echo $sub_menu->slug; ?>"><?php echo $sub_menu->page_name; ?></a></li>
                            <?php }} ?>
                        
                        <?php } ?>
                    
            <?php } ?>                                  
           <!-- Contact -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rd-navbar-aside-right"><a class="button button-sm button-secondary button-nina" href="<?php echo $site['panel_book']; ?>">Book</a></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Your help is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you are ever closing the <li> you open uder the line "<?php while($menu = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { ?>"

Comment: Oh yes @Sleepwalker thanks. but still how on earth i get the chils in a dropdown under parent?